# Meteor - resetting the database and creating an init script

Tags: mongodb, meteor

We are developing a Meteor application and we need some data to be readily available in the Mongo database after creation.

For example, we have a Mongo Collection named `Users` and we want to start with two users (say `John` and `Susan`). We don't want to do this manually, so after a Mongo reset it would be great if these data were added automatically to the Mongo database of the application thanks to a script.

What is the best and "most polished" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

The first, simple and maybe naive solution is to use some start-up script, like `/dev/init_data.js`:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if(typeof someCollection.findOne() === 'undefined') {
    someCollection.insert(...);
  }
});
```

But that would go into deployment... Unless you ***manually*** (ugh) erase the `/dev` folder before deploying or do some other ugly trick to get the code to be inactive. We don't want this code deployed at all.
So let's use a debug [package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs) instead!

```
meteor create --package devinitdata
```

In your fresh `package.js` file:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'devinitdata',
  ...
  debugOnly : true //!
});
```

And you can just write your init code in the [package files](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles) to fill your collections with all kind of messy data.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a db_init.js file with something like:

```
if (Meteor.isServer && (process && process.env && process.env.NODE_ENV === "development")) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    var newUser = {
        username: 'test',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        profile: {
            phone: '555-555-5555'
        },
        password: 'test'
    };

    Accounts.createUser(newUser);

  });
}
```

This could be coupled with something like percolatestudio/meteor-factory